# Accessing parent class variables in constructor PHP

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

I have the following classes.

```
class User extends GenericObject {
    private $table='users';
    private $primary_key='id';
}

class Animal extends GenericObject {
    private $table='animals';
    private $primary_key='id';
}

class GenericObject {
    public static function create_from_db($params) {
        $self = new self();
        //Build PDO query here

        //These echo statemtns fail
        echo $self->table;
        echo $self->primary_key;

        return $self;
    }
}
```

In my code that interfaces with these classes I want to do:

```
$animal=Animal::create_from_db($params);
$user=User::create_from_db($other_params);
```

My point of using the superclass is so I don't have to duplicate the create_from_db function over and over.

I tried overwriting the parent class and calling it but I'm not sure of the "proper" way to accomplish what I am trying to accomplish.

Any tips

Comment: By `variable` you mean properties? You could try `parent::`. Note if a class extends from another class then you should have all the properties on the child class given that they're not private on the parent class.

Comment: Stop trying to make active record. You should not mix persistence and domain logic.

Answer (score 1):

To have access to these variables you should fix two things. Make the properties "protected" instead of private, so that they can be accessed from the parent class and change the new statement to use "new static()" as that will instantiate the Animal or User class instead of "new self()" as that instantiates the GenericObject class.

```
class User extends GenericObject {
    protected $table='users';
    protected $primary_key='id';
}

class Animal extends GenericObject {
    protected $table='animals';
    protected $primary_key='id';
}

class GenericObject {
    public static function create_from_db($params=[]) {
        $self = new static();
        //Build PDO query here

        //These echo statements will not fail
        echo $self->table . PHP_EOL;
        echo $self->primary_key . PHP_EOL;

        return $self;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

"My point of using the superclass is so I don't have to duplicate the create_from_db function over and over." This is wrong, use a trait for that. Code defined in traits does have access to private fields of the classes that import them.